# A hotel greeter named Alfred

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, mvc

Is there any way of improving this code? (Here's a [JSFiddle with an example and comments](http://jsfiddle.net/wDRL7/3/))

Example: A hotel greeter can greet guests and accepts tips, but it's impossible to see the total of tips a greeter has received.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>

            []___  
           /    /\     O <span id="alfred-says"><!-- the view --></span>
          /____/__\   /|\
          |[][]||||   / \
                     ALFRED

        </pre>
        <button onclick="javascript:alfred('greet')">Arrive at Hotel</button>
        <button onclick="javascript:alfred('acceptTip', 10)">Tip Alfred $10</button>
        <script>
        var HOTEL, alfred;
        HOTEL = {}; // Namespace
        (function (HOTEL) {
            // Reuseable controller
            var controllerPrototype = {
                greet: function () {
                    this.model.view.innerHTML = '"' + this.model.greeting + '"';
                },
                acceptTip: function (tip) {
                    this.model.tips += tip;
                    this.model.view.innerHTML = '"' + this.model.thankyou + '"';
                }
            };
            // Create a new greeter
            HOTEL.newGreeter = function (view) {
                var controller = Object.create(controllerPrototype);
                controller.facet = function () {
                    var args, method;
                    method = arguments[0];
                    args = 2 <= arguments.length ? [].slice.call(arguments, 1) : [];
                    if (method === "facet" || method === "model" || (controller[method] == null)) {
                        return undefined;
                    }
                    // Model, View and real Controller are never exposed
                    return controller[method].apply(controller, args);
                };
                controller.model = {
                    greeting: "Hello",
                    thankyou: "Thank you",
                    tips: 0,
                    view: view
                };
                return controller.facet;
            };
        }(HOTEL));
        // Alfred only exposes the controller facet. His tips are a secret...
        alfred = HOTEL.newGreeter(document.getElementById("alfred-says"));
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Goals:

- Keep it DRY
- Keep it MVC
- Make sure anyone with access to a "greeter" can never manipulate the view or model directly.

Limitations:

- To avoid clutter, avoid type checking to avoid simple errors unless it is necessary to guarantee integrity.

Some specific thoughts:

- Is there a better way of passing model and view into the controller?
- Is there a better way of communicating with the controller?
- Is there a good way of making a more general view?
- Any other improvements?

Comment: by "principle of least concern" do you mean "[principle of least knowledge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)"? or "[principle of least effort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_effort)"?

Comment: I don't know where I got "Concerns" from, I meant to write "[principle of least privilege](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege)", which I suppose is the same as or similar to "principle of least knowledge"

Comment: Principle of Least Knowledge, also known as the "Law of Demeter", has nothing to do with the "Principle of Least Privilege". [Former](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) is about *not talking to strangers*, [latter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) is more related to security / authorisations.

Comment: My intention is that nothing with access to "Alfred" should be able to access or manipulate anything in a way that was not intended, so Principle of Least Knowledge/Law of Demeter is closer (although "has nothing to do with" is a bit of a stretch...).

Comment: The view should probably be known by model rather than the controller, and encapsulated in an object that abstracts away what the view is.

Comment: @JosefOttosson is this actual code from a project, or is it example code?

Comment: @Dagg it started as a small exploratory spin-off project from SVG Input Elements, but is now it's own.

Comment: @JosefOttosson in that case, isn't this mediator pattern a bit of a sledgehammer for a project which only does two very simple things (print a greeting and increment a counter)? If I reviewed this, my advice would be along those lines.

Comment: @Dagg Well, the purpose is to have a solid foundation to build upon. If I only wanted the stick man to say two phrases I could have put it all in the onclick attributes. The MVC, DRY and Law of Demeter, plus good coding standards in general, are what's interesting to review, I would say.

Comment: @JosefOttosson could you update your question to explain the full scope of this project? You say you want a foundation to build upon; what is it you are building here? Is it a game, a tool, or something else? As it stands, the MVC paradigm and mediator pattern do not seem to be a good fit for this project, and reviewing your mediator/MVC implementation in the context of a project for which it may be unfit seems unproductive.

Comment: Based on the feedback in these comments I can only conclude that my interests are a little too theoretic for CR. Thank you for your interest, I'll surely be back again when I have more practical headaches!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the comments, I guess you would like a theoretical review ;)

- This:

  ```
  <button onclick="javascript:alfred('greet')">Arrive at Hotel</button>
  <button onclick="javascript:alfred('acceptTip', 10)">Tip Alfred $10</button>
  ```

  in my mind should be wired by the controller,  that is, the linking of UI elements to data and UI changes
- This:

  ```
  greet: function () {
      this.model.view.innerHTML = '"' + this.model.greeting + '"';
  },
  ```

  has your controller access data straight in your view, updating the DOM. This is wrong in my mind. The view should have functions that the controller can call with either the model as a parameter or already passed in advance.
- `Object.create(controllerPrototype);` <- Any reason you are eschewing `new` and `prototype` ?
- Not that it truly matters but, `method === "model"` will not catch `new String('model')`
- `args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);` works as well as the ternary

All in all, I think this could use some more polishing.

Answer (score 2):

- Surely controllers need not understand what `innerHTML` is, that is a views job
- Likewise controllers have no need to understand that a tip is an accumulated value, thats the models job
- You dont really have a View (aka Mediator in PureMVC) in that code, you have a html element. A view should abstract away its implementation so the controller has no idea what is happening under the covers, and thereby does not get polluted by specific code.
- A real view would be given a selector, know how to draw itself and its subcomponents, as well as wire up THEIR views (every component should have a view -- use the word Mediator here in your mind, 'view' makes you think wrong)
- A Mediator should know nothing about the outside world, its job is to draw itself, expose methods for changing its display, expose methods for applying data, and emit events to a pub/sub system where a controller from a CONTROLLERS (plural) pool leaps into action to handle that one event.
- Your Model has a view reference for pure convenience to you. This is wrong, there should be as I said, multiple mediators and if you do things right the one time you need to access them is in an event, by the appropriate controller -- so every event message has its `source` which is the Mediator.
- The other time you need to access them is when the Model changes (also an event), so the controller corresponding to that event should get its mediator reference(s) from the registry of mediators (where mediators go to be born).
- Your model is naked data, a model should have an accessor/CRUD layer to hide implementation. Model should NOT have validators (not that you do), that is the controllers job, but debatable.
- All components of the MVC system should be registered and accessed via their registry, not through dot notation. They should be treated as if they are or may become transitory (you hold no refs to them, you get them, use them and let them go).
- Take a look at how it is done in PureMVC, which is an easy to understand, small, extensible, language agnostic MVC.